# Performing binomial (not just binary) regression in Python / statsmodels

Tags: regression, statsmodels

In R I can perform a binomial regression, where the number of successes and failures depends on a predictor variable `x`, e.g.

```
glm(matrix(c(succ, fail), ncol=2) ~ x, data=tbTest, family="binomial")
```

Can I do the same with Python's `statsmodels` or, alternatively, any other module? When I try

```
smf.glm('(succ, fail) ~ x', tbTest, family=binom).fit()
```

I get

> PatsyError: Number of rows mismatch between data argument and succ, fail (6 versus 2)
> (succ, fail) ~ x
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^

Here is the MRE:

```py
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
binom = sm.families.Binomial()
tbTest = pd.DataFrame({
  'x'    : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  'succ' : [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
  'fail' : [1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3],
})
lrTest = smf.glm('(succ, fail) ~ x', tbTest, family=binom).fit()
```

Comment: correct formula is `'succ + fail` ~ x' , `+` concatenates also on the left side

Comment: Thanks, Josef. Do you care posting an answer, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct formula is `'succ + fail ~ x'` , `+` concatenates also on the left side.

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
binom = sm.families.Binomial()
tbTest = pd.DataFrame({
  'x'    : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  'succ' : [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
  'fail' : [1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3],
})
lrTest = smf.glm('succ + fail ~ x', tbTest, family=binom).fit()
print(lrTest.summary())
                 Generalized Linear Model Regression Results                  
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:       ['succ', 'fail']   No. Observations:                    6
Model:                            GLM   Df Residuals:                        4
Model Family:                Binomial   Df Model:                            1
Link Function:                  Logit   Scale:                          1.0000
Method:                          IRLS   Log-Likelihood:                -5.0449
Date:                Tue, 18 Apr 2023   Deviance:                       2.9569
Time:                        08:13:32   Pearson chi2:                     2.36
No. Iterations:                     5   Pseudo R-squ. (CS):             0.7957
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept      3.6577      1.434      2.551      0.011       0.847       6.468
x             -0.9310      0.375     -2.483      0.013      -1.666      -0.196
==============================================================================
```

Answer (score 1):

`statsmodels` can do that. The correct syntax is

```py
smf.glm('succ/succ+fail ~ x', tbTest, family=binom).fit()
```

Here is a complete example:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

# simulate some data:
x = np.linspace(-2, 2, 50)              # the predictor variable
p = 1 / (1 + np.exp(x))                 # the probability of 'success'
n = 1 + np.random.poisson(3, len(p))    # the number of 'trials'
succ = np.random.binomial(n, p, len(p)) # the number of 'successes'
fail = n - succ                         # the number of 'fails'

# arrange them in a data frame:
tbTest = pd.DataFrame({'x' : x, 'succ' : succ, 'fail' : n-succ })

# the binomial regression itself:
binom = sm.families.Binomial()
lrTest = smf.glm('succ/succ+fail ~ x', tbTest, family=binom).fit()
lrTest.summary2()

# visualise the result:
plt.plot(x, succ/n, '.', c='steelblue')
plt.plot(x, lrTest.predict(), c='firebrick')
plt.grid(linestyle=':')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('p')
plt.title('Binomial regression (simulation)')
```

It produces:

```
              Results: Generalized linear model
==============================================================
Model:              GLM              AIC:            118.5180 
Link Function:      Logit            BIC:            -133.2729
Dependent Variable: ['succ', 'fail'] Log-Likelihood: -57.259  
Date:               2023-04-18 10:48 LL-Null:        -87.964  
No. Observations:   50               Deviance:       54.504   
Df Model:           1                Pearson chi2:   44.8     
Df Residuals:       48               Scale:          1.0000   
Method:             IRLS                                      
---------------------------------------------------------------
            Coef.   Std.Err.     z     P>|z|    [0.025   0.975]
---------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept  -0.2039    0.1617  -1.2611  0.2073  -0.5209   0.1130
x          -1.0716    0.1592  -6.7311  0.0000  -1.3836  -0.7596
=============================================================
```

and:

[image: Binomial regression (simulation)]